# Partaly "free_y" Facet Wrap with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, facet

my goal is to produce a column graph showing different element concentrations.
there is a very wide range so I want to customise the scale of my faceted graph into 3 groups.
that way the graphs are able to show the variation in samples for each element and still be comparable between elements,

so idealy I would have 3 different scales for Groups 1,2,and 3 in the graph below.

[image]

this is the code to make the above graph

```
ggplot(binded)+
  aes(y=mean,
      x=sample,
      group=id)+
  geom_col(aes(fill=element))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd,
                    ymax = mean + sd))+
  facet_wrap(rang~element)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,15,by=1),
                     name = "Sample ID")+
  scale_y_continuous(name="Elemental Conc. (mg/kg)",labels = comma)+
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

and the data used is below

[image]

if i swich the facting to  `facet_wrap(rang~element,scales = "free_y")` then i get

[image]

is there any way to mage the scales only free within each group of rang?

i suspect im going to have to just create 3 seperat graphs.

Comment: I think you made this too complicated. I would make your x the element, your y the concentration, group by sample (factor first to conserve order) and then `facet_grid` by the way you want to split the groups.

Comment: can you post your data using `dput(binded)`?

Comment: No: There is no way for partial free scale y in a facet_wrap. But you can make three ggplots for each group and then combine them, e.g. using `patchwork`

Comment: You may want to checkout the `lemon` package.  [Some information and vignettes can be found here](https://github.com/stefanedwards/lemon).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Danlooo for the suggestion of `patchwork` that package and creating 3 separate graphs + plus another one for the y axis label proved successful.

I produced several graphs with the original code and a data frame filters for different concentrations. and the following patchwork code to produce the following graph

```
 p5<-(p1 | p2) / p3+ plot_layout(heights=c(1,2))
(p4+p5)+plot_layout(widths = c(1, 25))
```

[image]